# ASP .NET Core (Net 6) POST Read Array from Form Data

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple API I am writing which includes a POST method to insert a new record into a couple of database tables. The data is coming from form data.

One of the items is a collection which includes a few fields.

I am using Swagger to test and when I Post the form data the collection field is blank.

Controller - Post endpoint

```
[HttpPost("addboardmember")]
        public IActionResult PostBoardMember([FromForm] MemberForm memberData)
        {
            try
            {
                _memberRepository.PostBoardMember(memberData);
                
                var newMember = _memberRepository.GetMembers().SingleOrDefault(m => m.SSN == memberData.SSN);
                var newMemberId = newMember.Member_ID;

                var boardArray = memberData.BoardForms;


                return Ok();
               //return Ok() is temporary, will return 201 with appropriate data
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Couldn't Save record??" + ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }
            
        }
```

MemberForm class  (Abbreviated to highlight the main fields and the field I am struggling with populating: BoardForms

```
public class MemberForm
    {
        [Required, NotNull]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
        [Required, NotNull]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
       
        [Required, NotNull]
        public string SSN {get; set;}

       


        public virtual ICollection<BoardForm> BoardForms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

BoardForm class:

```
public class BoardForm
    {
        public int Board_ID { get; set; }

        public int StartYear { get; set; }

        public int EndYear { get; set; }
    }
```

When I test Post API endpoint using Swagger the BoardForms field has a count of zero.
[image: Board Forms Count Shows 0]

Swagger input.

[image]

I will have additional business logic to create a record based on each record in the BoardForm array.

I do not know how I am supposed to access the array being sent in the Form Data which is setup as an ICollection.

Browser Developer Tools payload:
[image: Browser Payload]

All the elements shown above in the payload screenshot are mapped to their correct elements an I can see the values with the exception of the 'BoardForms' array.

Comment: Q: Have you looked at the actual, HTTP-level requests/responses, in either/both the MSVS debugger or Chrome/Edge Developer Tools?  Exactly what (if any) data is being received by your "Post" handler when you "Save" the form?  Q: Have you looked in SSMS (or equivalent) to see what data is being saved to the DB?

Comment: I am receiving the data for all the other fields, and I verified my API can write those to the database table.
In the included screenshot the email field shows the entered data. Most of my fields are currently options so I left those blank.
When I have added a screenshot from the browser developer tools which shows the payload being sent.
I can access all the fields with the exception of the BoardForms field. When I look at the values Visual Studio when the API is running I am shown a count of 0 for BoardForms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You're using the wrong attribute **and** you're formatting your requests incorrectly.

  - Use `[FromForm]` when you want ASP.NET to bind HTML `<form>` data posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

    - You cannot use `[FromForm]` for JSON data.
  - Use `[FromBody]` to have ASP.NET use some configured `Content-Type`-specific binder to populate an object.

    - ASP.NET Core supports `application/json` by default, I don't know what other types are supported in-box (e.g. XML, `DataContract`, etc) but it is extensible as you can also support gRPC, for example.
    - You *probably should not* be using either `<form>` content-types (`multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) for any "Web APIs" because those are specific to the idiosyncrasies of HTML's `<form>` and are unsuitable for describing structured data (such as arbitrary lists of data, or keyed collections), while ASP.NET *does* support binding `<form>` / `FormData` to objects it is unsuitable for JSON documents.

      - If you're using `multipart/form-data` to allow for binary uploads from client-libraries and headless clients (and *not* human-operated web-browsers) then I'd advise you to redesign your web-service's to accept binary file uploads as separate `PUT`/`POST` requests and to not combine DTOs with binary data in the same request.

        - While ASP.NET Core *can* bind objects to JSON
          (`application/json`) *and* `IFormFile` from other `multipart/form-data` request parts, this functionality isn't built-in nor turnkey: you'll need to write your own model-binder to handle this scenario - and I don't think it's worth the effort. YMMV.

so change this:

```
[HttpPost("addboardmember")]
public IActionResult PostBoardMember([FromForm] MemberForm memberData)
{
}
```

to this:

```
[HttpPost("addboardmember")]
public IActionResult PostBoardMember([FromBody] MemberForm memberData)
{
}
```

And you might want to ensure your `Controller` class has `[ApiController]` applied to it.

Comment: I believe I am sending the data as a multipart/form-data. All the other fields are populated as expected in the API. Is it because the the BoardForms field is being sent as a JSON object?

Comment: @Tom You cannot have inline JSON in a `multipart/form-data` request body without specifically configuring a custom Model Binder to handle it. If this is an "API" as you describe, why aren't you using JSON consistently?

Comment: @Dai: I believe you hit the nail on the head.  I love that frameworks like ASP.Net "abstract" away a lot of low-level "grunge" ... but I hate that means many developers  never really get to understand the different ways HTTP response data can be formatted, or  details about how "bindings" really work ... and the many potential "gotcha's you can encounter while using them.

Comment: @paulsm4 Wait until you come across my polemics about WebForms...