# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API cannot receive posted values: always null

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

My react front-end posted json data and ASP.NET Core back-end always got value = null. How can it get values?

I tried `[FromForm]`, `[FromBody]` and `[FromQuery]`, but value is always null.

I'm working with .NET 7.

Back-end always got data with skills and availabilities null, but other parameters got values

```
public class ServicesRequest
{
    public int? ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<SkillRequest> Skills { get; set; }
    public List<AvailabilityRequest> Availabilities { get; set; }
    public IFormFileCollection ServicesImages { get; set; }
}

public class SkillRequest
{
    public int? SkillId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityRequest
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeeks { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly StartDate { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly EndDate { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult<ServicesResponse>> UpsertServicesAsync([FromForm] ServicesRequest servicesRequest)
{}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmE1r.png)

The result is the same in Postman, Swagger and react application

Swagger:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJgBM.png)

I apply this parameters in the postman and finally works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nwcR.png)

Comment: could you provide the payload in request or how you send request in postman/swagger

Comment: payload in swagger form data Skills: {
  "skillId": 1,
  "name": "testing"
}
UserId: 
Price: 10
ServiceTypeId: 1
AddressId: 1
ServiceId: 
Title: test
CategoryId: 1
Availabilities: {
  "dayOfWeeks": 0,
  "startDate": "10:00",
  "endDate": "12:00"
}
Description: test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `Skills` and `Availabilities` is `List<T>`, So you can't just pass data as the normal property, You need to pass data like:

```
"skills": [
    {
      "skillId": 1,
      "name": "xxxx"
    }
  ]
```

Model

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SkillRequest> skills { get; set; }
        public List<AvailabilityRequest> Availabilities { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**=======Update===============**
[image]

Comment: Hi Xinran, I'm did the changes but I still receive null or 0

Comment: `skills` and `Availabilities` still get null or 0?

Comment: I declare the payload with [] and I receive count = 0 in the parameter Skills

Comment: Hi @Francisco Ojeda CL, I am not sure how you send request, but refer the answer i updated, It work successfully.

Comment: Xinran, that's work with [FromBody] but i need to post all data with [FromForm] maybe is not possible.

Comment: @Francisco Ojeda CL,  Swagger does not support the transmission of this format by default, If you wanna send data in the form, you can use postman to do like what i updated, `PropertyName[index].modepropertyname`

Comment: Finally works with that implementation, thank Xinran

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be that an array is expected for skills and Availabilities, but you are sending objects in the payload. Try to send array in the json like this:

```
[
    { 
      "skillId": 1, 
      "name": "testing"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi konawige, I still receive null or 0 with that change

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[FromForm]` as you have image as attachment, and you should send your payload `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, and the body should look like this

```
serviceId=1&...&skills[0].skillId=1&skills[0].name=name+with+space&skills[1].skillId=2&skills[1].name=another+long+name&availabilities[0].dayOfWeek=2&availabilities[0].startDate=2023-08-02&availabilities[0].endDate=2023-08-05&availabilities[1].dayOfWeek=3&availabilities[1].startDate=...&availabilities[1].endDate=...
```

You might also want to reference the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748575/6372292) talking about how the image be uploaded in the separate request body, instead of designing to upload the image together with your JSON document. And for this, you can turn back your request to [FromBody] and send as `Content-Type: application/json` and send the JSON document, while the file is uploaded in other endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a simple request class with a single property. My setter on the property of the request class was private. Once I made it public it worked correctly.